# Sequelize - Search query with criteria on nested entity

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize & Posgresql. I'm also using [sequelize-typescript](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript).

I have a model Compte like :

```
export class Compte extends Model<Compte> {

    @ForeignKey(() => CompteRevision)
    @Column
    derniereRevisionId: number;

    @BelongsTo(() => CompteRevision, 'derniereRevisionId')
    public derniereRevision: CompteRevision;

    @Unique
    @AllowNull(false)
    @Column(DataType.STRING)
    public email: string;
}
```

and CompteRevision like :

```
export class CompteRevision extends Model<CompteRevision> {

    @Column(DataType.BIGINT)
    public compteId: number;

    @Column(DataType.STRING)
    public nom: string;

    @Column(DataType.STRING)
    public prenom: string;
}
```

I am trying to make a search request (based on a string searchText), to retrieve the accounts where:

- Compte.email is ILIKE : "%" + searchText + "%"
- OR
- Compte.derniereRevision.nom is ILIKE : "%" + searchText + "%"
- OR
- Compte.derniereRevision.prenom is ILIKE : "%" + searchText + "%"

After looking to many answers on SO, I tried to do it like :

```
public async search(searchText: string): Promise<Array<Compte>> {
        return Compte.findAll({
            where: {
                email: { [Server.sequelize.Op.iLike]: "%" + searchText + "%" }
            },
            include: [{  
                model: CompteRevision, where: {
                    nom: { [Server.sequelize.Op.iLike]: "%" + searchText + "%" },
                    prenom: { [Server.sequelize.Op.iLike]: "%" + searchText + "%" }
                }
            }]
        });
    }
```

But I'm not sure that the include clause is doing what I want. Actually, this method always return an empty Array. Does someone know how to do such find requests by checking criteria on nested entities like CompteRevision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go :

```
return Compte.findAll({
    where: {
        $or : [
            { email: { $iLike : "%" + searchText + "%" } },
            { '$derniereRevision.nom$' : { $iLike : "%" + searchText + "%" }, }, // <--- Magic is here
            { '$derniereRevision.prenom$' : { $iLike : "%" + searchText + "%" } } // <--- Magic is here
        ]
    },
    include: [{  
        model: CompteRevision
    }]
});
```

> **NOTES :**
>
> `$CompteRevision.nom$` , `$table_name.column$` syntax is to query on
>   included table ,  without `$$` sequelize will not consider as table
>   name with column. Change this `CompteRevision` with your table name
>
> When you do query inside include model , it will make inner join with
>   included table , to make it left join you can use `required:false`,
>   but its not the case that you need here
>
> Instead of using `Server.sequelize.Op.iLike` long syntax , you can use
>   short operators `$iLike` , **[read more](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators-security)**

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my day !! Actually I had to change '$CompteRevision.nom$' by '$derniereRevision.nom$' to make it work, I will edit your answer to include it and validate it as the good answer. My purpose was to discover that magic that is not properly explained in the docs, and you did it.

Comment: About the $iLike alias, I understood that sequelize advises against using it, for security reasons. According to the doc you quoted, it is said that the long syntax is safer (or maybe I totally misunderstood it).

Comment: Thanks it works, it finally works I knew it was possible, this is awesome